# Generic 'ApplicationException' in XP-Framework

Tags: php, exception

Is there any generic exception type except XPException that I can throw?

Java and .NET have ApplicationException. Is there a similar exception type in the XP-Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XP-Framework doesn't provide a generic non-specific exception type. So far we've believed in reusing the exceptions from `lang`: IllegalArgument, IllegalAccess, IllegalState, ElementNotFound, etcetera. Not saying this can't be changed:)

Comment: Ok, thx. I created a feature request for adding `ConfigurationException` and `ApplicationException`. https://github.com/xp-framework/xp-framework/issues/346

Comment: This pull request has been merged.

Answer (score 1):

For service-like things, there is a `util.ServiceException`. This is not generally useful, though.

Comment: Thx. I have considered using this, but then I checked the API doc. It says something about `the server's fault message's faultcode` and has a reference to `SoapRpcRouter`.

Comment: Yap, this is where it all came from: SOAP was the first "RPC" implementation seriously supported by the XP Framework.